# How to configure mail in localhost

Tags: php, phpmailer

Here is code After using mailer function.What Wrong I have done in this code That  got the error and how can rectify this.I also enable IMAP in my gmail account, ssl_module from Apache and extension=php_openssl.dll is uncommented

```
Here is configuration code
<?php
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// ---------- adjust these lines ---------------------------------------
$mail->Username = "pankaj.kumar.dimple@gmail.com"; // your GMail user name
$mail->Password = "p@nkaj1390"; 
$mail->AddAddress("smart.developer1990@gmail.com"); // recipients email
$mail->FromName = "pankaj"; // readable name

$mail->Subject = "Subject title";
$mail->Body    = "Here is the message you want to send to your friend."; 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // GMail
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->From = $mail->Username;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($mail);
if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
    echo "Message has been sent";
?>
-----------------------------------------------------------
PHPMailer Object
(
[Priority] => 3
[CharSet] => iso-8859-1
[ContentType] => text/plain
[Encoding] => 8bit
[ErrorInfo] => 
[From] => pankaj.kumar.dimple@gmail.com
[FromName] => pankaj
[Sender] => 
[ReturnPath] => 
[Subject] => Subject title
[Body] => Here is the message you want to send to your friend.
[AltBody] => 
[MIMEBody:protected] => 
[MIMEHeader:protected] => 
[mailHeader:protected] => 
[WordWrap] => 0
[Mailer] => smtp
[Sendmail] => /usr/sbin/sendmail
[UseSendmailOptions] => 1
[PluginDir] => 
[ConfirmReadingTo] => 
[Hostname] => 
[MessageID] => 
[MessageDate] => 
[Host] => smtp.gmail.com
[Port] => 465
[Helo] => 
[SMTPSecure] => 
[SMTPAuth] => 1
[Username] => pankaj.kumar.dimple@gmail.com
[Password] => 
[AuthType] => 
[Realm] => 
[Workstation] => 
[Timeout] => 10
[SMTPDebug] => 
[Debugoutput] => echo
[SMTPKeepAlive] => 
[SingleTo] => 
[SingleToArray] => Array
    (
    )

[LE] => 

[DKIM_selector] => 
[DKIM_identity] => 
[DKIM_passphrase] => 
[DKIM_domain] => 
[DKIM_private] => 
[action_function] => 
[Version] => 5.2.4
[XMailer] => 
[smtp:protected] => 
[to:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => smart.developer1990@gmail.com
                [1] => 
            )

    )

[cc:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[bcc:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[ReplyTo:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[all_recipients:protected] => Array
    (
        [smart.developer1990@gmail.com] => 1
    )

[attachment:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[CustomHeader:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[message_type:protected] => 
[boundary:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[language:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[error_count:protected] => 0
[sign_cert_file:protected] => 
[sign_key_file:protected] => 
[sign_key_pass:protected] => 
[exceptions:protected] => 
)
```

Mailer Error: The following From address failed: pankaj.kumar.dimple@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected

Comment: PLEASE CHANGE YOUR GMAIL PASSWORD ASAP (Sorry for yelling).

Comment: this is not my real pw

Comment: You need to post your code.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you're using an old version of PHPMailer - [get the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Base your code on the gmail example provided with PHPMailer.

In order to tell if you're doing anything wrong, you should post your code as part of the question.

Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` so that you can see what's going on - it's likely you will see more useful error messages in the SMTP transcript. Also refer to [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: 2015-01-31 10:40:20 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:465, t=300, opt=array ( ) 2015-01-31 10:40:21 Connection: opened

Comment: I download set up from here and integrate it https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Your output contains `[Version] => 5.2.4`, which is old, and the syntax of your code still looks like an old example. Did you try the debug settign I suggested?